Turtlebot4 camera doesn't have non compressed depth image topic
i need to run rtabmap odometry on my turtlebot4 (visual odometry), i need uncompressed image in input but i have only the compressed topic image (/turtlebot4_4/oakd/rgb/preview/image_raw/compressedDepth), is there a way to obtain images formatted in the right way?
